# People are not able to see the posts made by my app

Tags: facebook, post

My application posts funny pictures links to my Facebook pages. It was working fine till yesterday night when posts started to show up only on the page's wall, NOT people home feed. Now all the posts made by the app are NOT seen by anyone. Is this a Facebook problem ? Did they change anything ?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://alwaysupward.com/blog/fb-fans-arent-seeing-your-posts-and-how-to-fix-it/comment-page-2/.  Anyway, if the problem only surfaced yesterday, the only people likely to know anything meaningful about it is Facebook itself.

Comment: I already have the settings set to "Show In News Feed" and I don't see any posts.

Comment: To be a little clearer, if you didn't change anything in your app, and this problem showed up *yesterday,* Facebook is the only one likely to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this same thing happening to posts made to Profiles from the app I built. They aren't visible to me or anyone else. What's strange is that Facebook hands the app back a Post ID, which indicates that the post even succeeded, but when I concatenate the URL it would imply, there's nothing served at all.

This is a bug for sure. I haven't been able to find anything else mentioned about it anywhere else yet.